# Changing divs on click

Tags: html, click

I've got code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">somethung here</div>
  <div class="box">somethung here</div>
  <div class="box">somethung here</div>
  <div class="box">somethung here</div>
  <div class="box">somethung here</div>
</div>
```

How to do this:

When I click on a div.box It will have for example red background, and when I click another div.box It will also have red background, but the previous clicked div.box will return to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job
http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/XzQ5h/

Comment: Yes It's working. Now next thing. How can I run a function for the element that was clicked before?

Comment: Can you accept the answer as helpful to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Give each div a unique id..and hook an onclick event in javascript. Check for the id of the box whose color you want to change and apply that color code accordingly.